# logstash coerce not adding value that can be used in index name

Tags: logstash

I have the following filter for logstash:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    # Sets the default value for application, in case someone forgot to set it in their                                                                    
    # Gelf configuration                                                                                                                                   
    coerce => { "application" => "unknown_application" }
  }
}
```

My expectation is that if I don't have a field named "application" it should add that field, and make the name "unknown_application".

Here is my output:

```
output {
  # (Un)comment for debugging purposes                                                                                                                     
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
        index => "app-%{application}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I expect if I log something with no application it should get stuck into the app-unknown_application-(date) index in elasticsearch.  When I add a message with nothing in the "application" field I instead get my items stuck into a collection named as follows:

app-%{application}-2020.09.30

Clearly something went wrong with the coerce - it doesn't seem to have done anything.  Any idea what I may have done incorrectly?

The full logstash configuration file is below:

```
input {
  gelf {
    id => "gelf"
    use_udp => false
    use_tcp => true
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "json_message"
  }
  prune {
   blacklist_names => [ "source_host", "facility" ]
  }
  mutate {
    # Sets the default value for application, in case someone forgot to set it in their                                                                    
    # Gelf configuration                                                                                                                                   
    coerce => { "application" => "unknown_application" }
  }
}

output {
  # (Un)comment for debugging purposes                                                                                                                     
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200/"]
        index => "app-%{application}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My expectation is that if I don't have a field named "application" it
> should add that field

No, coerce modifies fields that exist, but are null. You could try

if ! [application] { mutate { add_field => { "application" => "unknown_application" } } }